# invalid number oracle jdbc

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
String query =  "select NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR, avg(DISTANCE) as DISTANCE " +
                "from " +
                "(select NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR, " +
                "6387.7 * ACOS((sin(LATITUDE_DEPART / 57.29577951) * SIN(LATITUDE_ARRIVEE / 57.29577951)) + " +
                "(COS(LATITUDE_DEPART / 57.29577951) * COS(LATITUDE_ARRIVEE / 57.29577951) * " +
                "COS(LONGITUDE_ARRIVEE / 57.29577951 - LONGITUDE_DEPART / 57.29577951))) as DISTANCE " +
                "from " +
                "(select l.NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR, " +
                "regexp_substr(d1.COORDONNEES, '^[^,]+') as LATITUDE_DEPART, " +
                "trim(leading ',' FROM regexp_substr(d1.COORDONNEES, ',.*$')) AS LONGITUDE_DEPART, " +
                "regexp_substr(d2.COORDONNEES, '^[^,]+') as LATITUDE_ARRIVEE, " +
                "trim(leading ',' FROM regexp_substr(d2.COORDONNEES, ',.*$')) AS LONGITUDE_ARRIVEE " +
                "from LIVRAISONS l " +
                "inner join DEPOTS d1 on(l.NUMERO_DEPOT_DEPART = d1.NUMERO_DEPOT) " +
                "inner join DEPOTS d2 on(l.NUMERO_DEPOT_ARRIVE = d2.NUMERO_DEPOT) " +
                ")) " +
                "group by (NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR)";
```

But a java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number is being thrown. Does anyone know why? Because if I execute the query directly in sql using sqlplus it works fine.

Result of execution of the query using sqlplus:

```
NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR AVG(DISTANCE)
---------------- -------------
           1    507.064894
           2    703.326572
           5    846.966137
           4    511.914202
```

I've tried the following but the error still persists:

```
String query =  "select NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR, avg(DISTANCE) as DISTANCE " +
                "from " +
                "(select NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR, " +
                "to_number('6387.7') * ACOS((sin(LATITUDE_DEPART / to_number('57.29577951')) * SIN(LATITUDE_ARRIVEE / to_number('57.29577951'))) + " +
                "(COS(LATITUDE_DEPART / to_number('57.29577951')) * COS(LATITUDE_ARRIVEE / to_number('57.29577951')) * " +
                "COS(LONGITUDE_ARRIVEE / to_number('57.29577951') - LONGITUDE_DEPART / to_number('57.29577951')))) as DISTANCE " +
                "from " +
                "(select l.NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR, " +
                "to_number(regexp_substr(d1.COORDONNEES, '^[^,]+')) as LATITUDE_DEPART, " +
                "to_number(trim(leading ',' FROM to_number(regexp_substr(d1.COORDONNEES, ',.*$')))) AS LONGITUDE_DEPART, " +
                "to_number(regexp_substr(d2.COORDONNEES, '^[^,]+')) as LATITUDE_ARRIVEE, " +
                "to_number(trim(leading ',' FROM to_number(regexp_substr(d2.COORDONNEES, ',.*$')))) AS LONGITUDE_ARRIVEE " +
                "from LIVRAISONS l " +
                "inner join DEPOTS d1 on(l.NUMERO_DEPOT_DEPART = d1.NUMERO_DEPOT) " +
                "inner join DEPOTS d2 on(l.NUMERO_DEPOT_ARRIVE = d2.NUMERO_DEPOT) " +
                ")) " +
                "group by (NUMERO_CHAUFFEUR)";
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in sqlplus it executes fine. I added the result obtained to the question

Comment: Show how you get query result in java

Comment: Did you tried something like `resultSet.getInt("DISTANCE")` ?

Comment: the error happens during the execution of the query

Comment: @cildoz you very probably **do not** execute the **same** query in SQLPlus, I mean your Java string concatenation expression. So I'd suggest you to performs a sort of binary search to locate the part of the statement (column) which causes the problem. In lucky case you'll spot the problem yourself, if the mystery remains go to SO with this *minimal* example.

Comment: What are the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS? Your regex assume ',.' but is that the case? It may be different when you connect via JDBC than when you connect directly.

Answer (score 0):

An ORA-01722 error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a number.
`regexp_substr` would return string and you called it as LATITUDE_DEPART, then you do mathematics with that value which is not correct. you should first convert it as number. this might help you:

```
TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(d1.COORDONNEES, '^[^,]')) LATITUDE_DEPART
```

Do this for all same parts.

Comment: OK...but why is it running directly in the database with no error?

Comment: @cildoz did you do it for all variables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen maybe it's because java and sqlplus uses different dialects.

Comment: @cildoz your updated question is not correct yet. you should do it for all variables. you should use it for `trim` also.

Comment: I edited the question again, I added to_number to trim but the error persists